# Javascript daily countdown only showing for WordPress admins, not public?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

On our site we're trying to execute a script that counts down to midnight everyday, displays a message, and then "resets" at midnight.

The message is basically "Order within X1, Get By X2"

The script calculates X1 to be XX Hours XX Minutes until midnight. X2 is 5 days, after today (if today is the 1st, it would be the 2nd + 5 giving you the 7th, with the exception of Sunday, then it will automatically skip to the Monday immediately after).

The problem though is that for some reason this script refuses to load for the front-end user, yet as a logged in admin I can see the code.

```
<!-- Allows to add estimated delivery time to the product and/or cart page -->
<div class="dailytimer"><strong>Order within <span id='mycountdown' style="color: #FF0000;"></span>, Get it by <span id="delDate" style="color: #FF0000;"></span></strong></div>

<script>
// First part of output
var myreset = [00,00,00]; // at what time to reset - 19:40:00

// Added myCountDownDiv variable to prevent jquery from walking the DOM o every update
var myCountDownDiv = document.getElementById('mycountdown');

var mycountdown = startCountdown();

function startCountdown(){
  var enddate = calculateEndDate();
  return setInterval(function(){tickTock(calculateStartDate(),enddate)}, 1000);
}
function calculateStartDate(){ //this needs to be edited if using the server time
  return new Date();
}
function calculateEndDate(){
    var enddate = new Date();
    enddate.setHours(myreset[0]);
    enddate.setMinutes(myreset[1]);
    enddate.setSeconds(myreset[2]);
    return enddate;
}
function tickTock(startdate, enddate){
  var diff = enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime(); 
  d = diff >= 0 ? diff : diff + 24*3600*1000;
  var h = Math.floor(d / 3600 / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(d / 60 / 1000) - 60*h; 
  var s = Math.floor(d / 1000) - 3600*h - 60*m; 
  printCountdown(h,m,s);
}
function pluralize(word,count){
    return (count > 1) ? word+'s ' : word+' ';
}
function printCountdown(h,m,s){

  // Updated string concatination.  'and' was deisplayed after the seconds value
  var t = h + pluralize(' hour',h)+ m+pluralize(' minute',m);

  myCountDownDiv.innerText = t;

  // Removed jquery
  //$('#mycountdown').html(t); 
}

var fromDate = new Date();
fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 6);

if (fromDate.is().saturday() || fromDate.is().sunday()) { 
  fromDate = fromDate.next().monday();
}
document.getElementById('delDate').innerHTML = fromDate.toString('ddd MMMM dS');

</script>
```

It's using a date JS file I found online to calculate the dates. I'm also pretty sure there's a better way for us to "insert" the code into the page without literally coping it into a html widget inside of elementor (we're using it as a page builder) but I just haven't really thought of one off hand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm about 5 steps from wanting to just hit delete on the whole thing haha

Comment: What does PHP, wordpress or woocommerce have to do with this question?

Comment: Removed PHP & Woocommerce, although woocommerce probably could have stayed. The javascript is only showing to people who are logged in, which could be affected by PHP not loading somewhere correctly or wordpress / woocommerce preventing it from doing it's job.

Comment: Where are you calling this code?